# how to move box2d body with ccmoveto

Tags: ios, box2d, game-engine, cocos2d-x, physics

I want to move body with CCMove i am using the following code its just like a slab i want to move it from 1px to 100px and then move back from 100px to 1px its working fine if i only move from 1x to 100px but its behave unexpectedly when i move back

```
void MovableBlock::update(float dt) {

    b2Vec2 position;

    if(isForward) {
        positionAnimationImg =  ccpAdd(positionAnimationImg, animatableImage->getPosition());
        position = point_to_vec(ccp(this->getPositionX()+positionAnimationImg.x,this->getPositionY()));
    }
    else {

        positionAnimationImg =  ccpSub(positionAnimationImg, animatableImage->getPosition());
        position = point_to_vec(ccp(positionAnimationImg.x-this->getPositionX(),this->getPositionY()));
    }
     CCLog("%f:%f",this->getBody()->GetTransform().p.x,position.y);
    //CCLog("position>>  %f:%f",position.x,position.y);

    this->getBody()->SetTransform(b2Vec2(position.x,
                                         position.y),
                                  this->getBody()->GetAngle());
    animatableImage->setPosition(CCPointZero);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for point_to_vec?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CCMove with Box2d body then you attached a ccsprite with body and apply ccmove to sprite and transform body according to sprite position in update method.

Example: In Cocos@d-x

PTM_RATIO 32;

```
CCSprite *ball = CCSprite::create("icon.png");
ball->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/5, visibleSize.height/5));
this->addchild(ball);

b2BodyDef bdf ;
bdf.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bdf.position.Set((float)(visibleSize.width/(10*PTM_RATIO)), (float)(visibleSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
b2body hero = _world->CreateBody(&bdf);
hero->SetUserData(ball);

CCMoveBy *action = CCMoveBy::create(.5, CCPointMake(ball->getPositionX(), ball->getPositionY()-10));
CCMoveBy* action_back = (CCMoveBy*)action->reverse();
ball->runAction(CCSequence::create(action, action_back, NULL));
```

Now in Update method

```
CCSprite *sp1 = (CCSprite*)hero->GetUserData();
hero->SetTransform(b2Vec2(sp1->getPositionX()/PTM_RATIO, sp1->getPositionY()/PTM_RATIO), 0);
```